# Nexus Navigation Bar Overflow Button

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, uinavigationbar

I am currently improving an android application of mine and was wondering how I would be able to enable the overflow button on the nexus virtual navigation bar. Does anyone know how I would accomplish that?

[image: Example of Nexus Navigation Bar Overflow Button]

Comment: That would not be an improvement. That is the hallmark of an app that has not been updated since 2010.

Comment: That may be true, but I believe that it would be more convenient nonetheless.

Comment: The [menu button is dead](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three dots menu appears if your application does not have an ActionBar but declares a menu.
This kind of menu is made to support applications that do not use ActionBar menu on devices that have no hardware menu buttons.